# how to compare key to each other in a dictionary using javascript

Tags: javascript, wcf, dictionary

Here is my code, in which I am getting all data from wcf service and storing that data in to a dictionary with key.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var BasicHttpBinding = require('wcf.js').BasicHttpBinding
        , Proxy = require('wcf.js').Proxy
        , binding = new BasicHttpBinding(
                {
                })
        , proxy = new Proxy(binding, "http://localhost:9877/IDBReport/basicHttp")
        , message = "<Envelope xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" +
        "<Header />" +
        "<Body>" +
        "<OrderReport xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>" +
        "<value></value>" +
        "<value></value>" +
        "<value>+ req.query.start +</value>" +
        "<value>+ req.query.end +</value>" +
        "<value></value>" +
        "<value></value>" +
        "<value></value>" +
        "<value></value>" +
        "<value></value>" +
        "</OrderReport>" +
        "</Body>" +
        "</Envelope>";
proxy.send(message, "http://tempuri.org/IDBReport/OrderReport", function (message, ctx) {
    app.set("view engine", "jade");
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        parseString(message, function (err, result) {

            var response = result['s:Envelope']['s:Body'][0].OrderReportResponse[0].obj[0];
            var marketOrder = response['a:MarketOrder'];
            var dict1 = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < marketOrder.length; i++) {
                var keys1 = [];
                var keys = [];
                keys.push({
                    k1: marketOrder[i]['a:SecurityExchange'],
                    k2: marketOrder[i]['a:Symbol'],
                    k3: marketOrder[i]['a:MaturityMonthYear']

                });
                if (keys1.indexOf(keys[0].k1) && keys1.indexOf(keys[0].k2) && keys1.indexOf(keys[0].k3)) {
                    keys1.push(keys[0].k1, keys[0].k2, keys[0].k3);

                }
                for (var k1 in keys1[0]) {
                    var dict = {};
                    dict[keys1] = marketOrder[i];

                    if (dict1.indexOf(dict)) {
                        dict1.push(dict);
                    }
                }
            }
             for (var i = 0; i < dict1.length; i++) {
            for(var t in dict1[i]){
                 console.log(dict1[i]); //In 'dict1' all data is storing 
            }}

//            var serialized = JSON.stringify(dict1, null, 4);
//            console.log(serialized);
            res.render('MarketPosition', {mrkt: marketOrder});

        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

Now I want to compare all keys to each other, and want to print only those record which are not repeating by key(means if the key value is same, it should not print the data) how should I do that.

```
{ 'CME,ES,201703': 
   { 
     'a:CustomerOrFirm': [ 'Customer' ],
     'a:MaturityMonthYear': [ '201703' ],
     'a:Modifier': [ '' ],
     'a:MsgSeqNumber': [ '0' ],
     'a:MsgType': [ 'D' ],
     'a:OrdType': [ 'Limit' ],
     'a:SecurityExchange': [ 'CME' ],
     'a:SecurityId': [ [Object] ],
     'a:SecurityType': [ 'FUT' ],
     'a:SenderCompId': [ 'TRDFIRSTDTS' ],
     'a:SendingTime': [ '2016-12-20T11:44:05' ],
     'a:Symbol': [ 'ES' ],
     'a:TTOrderId': [ '' ],
     'a:TargetCompId': [ 'TTDEV25O' ],
     'a:TimeInForce': [ '0' ],
     'a:TmpOrderQty': [ '0' ],
     'a:TransactTime': [ '2016-12-20T11:44:04' ] } }
{ 'CME,ZB,201703': 
   { 'a:CustomerOrFirm': [ 'Customer' ],
     'a:MaturityMonthYear': [ '201703' ],
     'a:Modifier': [ '' ],
     'a:MsgSeqNumber': [ '0' ],
     'a:MsgType': [ 'D' ],
     'a:OrdType': [ 'Market' ],
     'a:SecurityExchange': [ 'CME' ],
     'a:SecurityId': [ [Object] ],
     'a:SecurityType': [ 'FUT' ],
     'a:SenderCompId': [ 'TRDFIRSTDTS' ],
     'a:SendingTime': [ '2016-12-20T11:44:52' ],
     'a:Symbol': [ 'ZB' ],
     'a:TTOrderId': [ '' ],
     'a:TargetCompId': [ 'TTDEV25O' ],
     'a:TimeInForce': [ '-' ],
     'a:TmpOrderQty': [ '0' ],
     'a:TransactTime': [ '2016-12-20T11:44:50' ]} }
{ 'CME,ZB,201703': 
   { 'a:CustomerOrFirm': [ 'Customer' ],
     'a:MaturityMonthYear': [ '201703' ],
     'a:Modifier': [ '' ],
     'a:MsgSeqNumber': [ '0' ],
     'a:MsgType': [ 'D' ],
     'a:OrdType': [ 'Market' ],
     'a:SecurityExchange': [ 'CME' ],
     'a:SecurityId': [ [Object] ],
     'a:SecurityType': [ 'FUT' ],
     'a:SenderCompId': [ 'TRDFIRSTDTS' ],
     'a:SendingTime': [ '2016-12-20T11:44:52' ],
     'a:Symbol': [ 'ZB' ],
     'a:TTOrderId': [ '' ],
     'a:TargetCompId': [ 'TTDEV25O' ],
     'a:TimeInForce': [ '-' ],
     'a:TmpOrderQty': [ '0' ],
     'a:TransactTime': [ '2016-12-20T11:44:50' ] } }
```

I am getting output like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push the used keys into an array, then as you loop through your dictionary, check if the array contains the key, if so, don't print it.

```js
var dictionary = [{ Key: 'A', Value: 'Key 1'}, { Key: 'A', Value: 'Key 1'}, { Key: 'B', Value: 'Key 2'}, { Key: 'B', Value: 'Key 2'}, { Key: 'C', Value: 'Key 3'}];

var usedKeys = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
  if (usedKeys.indexOf(dictionary[i].Key) == -1) {
    console.log(dictionary[i].Value);  
  }
  
  usedKeys.push(dictionary[i].Key);
}
```

Comment: means I have to store all key in other dictionary after that i have to compare both??

Comment: Its not working, for key and value its giving undefined.